# What package controls function for JavaScript

Tags: package

I am using Repl.it free account and my functions never display output values here is what comes from it:

```
fullName(){
    return `${this.first} ${this.last}`
} // this will not work


const user = {
  first: 'firstName',
  last: 'lastName',
  fullName() {
    return `${this.first} ${this.last}`
  }
}

console.log(`${user.fullName} this will not work`)
```

Comment: did you try invoking the function? (i.e. `console.log( user.fullName() );` )  - btw, 'does not work' is hardly a description of a problem - typically you want to look at the errors found in the console as it gives you more information as to what failed (sometimes even why it failed) - read our [ask] page for more hints on how to improve this question.

Answer (score 0):

I think the first function is incorrect, your syntax does not seem right.

I have provided a working sample syntax below.

The second object (with the function) is correct but the way you are invoking (calling) the function is not.

See below also a sample syntax on how to call it.

```js
fullName = (user) => {
  return user.first + ' ' + user.last;
}


const user = {
  first: 'firstName',
  last: 'lastName',
  fullName() {
    return `${this.first} ${this.last}`
  },
  anotherFullName: fullName
}

// first function
console.log(fullName(user) + ' this will not work');

// second (from user obj)
console.log(user.fullName() + ' this will not work');

// third (from user obj, using first function)
console.log(user.anotherFullName(user) + ' this will not work');
```